# Launch Agent unable to delete file and folder inside $HOME/Library/Containers/{yourAppFolder} macOS 14

Tags: macos, launchd, pkgbuild, macos-sonoma, launch-agent

In macOS 14 launch agent is unable to delete files and folders inside $HOME/Library/Containers/{yourAppFolder}

In older macOS (less than 14) launch agent able to uninstall the app container

I know apple has changed it's app sandbox permission - other apps or script can't access different developer accounts but here the launch agent is created by me while installing the app by the PKG installer